# git submodules as part of a build

Tags: git, build, git-submodules

I am trying to setup a git repository with a submodule repository inside it.  Lets call the 2 repos: Super & Sub for this example.  So I initialized the Super repo then did a `git submodule add` of the 2nd repo.  I committed the `.gitmodules` file with the Super repo so that when you do a `git clone --recursive` it pulls the submodule down along w/ the super.  Currently our urls are formatted like this:

```
ssh://user.name@serverUrl/path/to/repo.git
```

Now lets say I have 3 users: `user.a`, `user.b` and `user.c`.  `user.a` adds the submodule to the super repo.  `user.b` is the build server.  when `user.a` adds the submodule then `user.b` should get the submodule as `user.b` (NOT `user.a`).  The same goes for `user.c`  when he clones super and then does a commit, the log should reflect that it was committed by `user.c` and not as `user.a` (who added the submodule).  I suspect there is a way to specify the url of the submodule WITHOUT including the user.name as part of the url.  Which leads me to my question.  How can I properly setup my git repository such that the url does not include the username?  Presumably this involved copying some keys around, I'm just curious what is the proper way to do this.

many thanks
Ben

Comment: See the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031494/git-submodules-and-ssh-access

Answer (score 0):

Use gitolite so you can access all repos using the same user as far as the OS is concerned. Each ssh key will determine the id.

Comment: we ended up using https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/Home to do this, seems to work well so far...

Comment: That will work too :) But do checkout gitolite as it gives some more neat options for permissions per branch etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative urls for submodules in a manner:

```
[submodule "common/sub"]
path = common/sub
url = ../common/sub
```