# Git submodules best practice - always use ssh protocol over https?

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-submodules

I work on a lot of projects that use submodules, and some of them are added to their parent repos using a combination of both the [https and ssh protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html), as if it's not important which one.  SSH protocol has benefits that it uses ssh keys, but [requires users set up those keys first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031494/git-submodules-and-ssh-access).

I'd like to make a team policy: all projects *should* use [GitHub's git user with ssh protocol](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use) in submodules.  What are the pros/cons of said policy?

Answer (score 1):

Pro:

- ssh keys can be registered/revoked

Cons:

- ssh keys must be installed (`%HOME%\.ssh`)
- ssh keys, if you have multiple sets, [must be managed in a `%HOME%\.ssh\config` file (and the url must reflect that)](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996)
- ssh keys, if passphrase protected, would need an ssh-agent (to avoid entering the passphrase more than once per session)

I prefer [activating 2FA on GitHub account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309), and use only Personal Access Token, which can be revoked as well, but which are used as classic username/password way ([and which can be cached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309)) with **https url**.

In both cases, the [user need to be added as a collaborator to the GitHub repo](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-to-user-repo-denied-to-other-user).