# git submodule on github codespaces

Tags: git, github, codespaces

I have problem with submodule on github codespace.

When i use command

```
git submodule update --init
```

terminal show me

```
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,xxxxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
    git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Do you have access rights to that repository? Does it exist?

Comment: this is crazy I'm struggling with the same thing. I found this on the web, I'm trying it out now: https://github.community/t/how-to-checkout-recursively/136734

Comment: sse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031494/git-submodules-and-ssh-access

Answer (score 1):

> Github Codespace manages what they call a [*Developer Container*](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/introduction-to-dev-containers),
> which provides a fully featured development environment. Whenever you work in a codespace, you are using a dev container on a virtual machine.

As from [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-repository-access-for-your-codespaces):

> By default, your codespace is assigned a token scoped with `read` permission or `read` and `write` permission to the repository **from which it was created**

> If your project needs additional permissions for other repositories, you can configure this in the `devcontainer.json` file, as described in "[Setting additional repository permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-repository-access-for-your-codespaces#setting-additional-repository-permissions)"

To set all permissions for a given repository, use `"permissions": "read-all"` or `"permissions": "write-all"` in the repository object (the `.devcontainer.json` file):

```json
// .devcontainer.json
{
  "customizations": {
    "codespaces": {
      "repositories": {
        "my_org/my_repo": {
          "permissions": "write-all"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, through the `.devcontainer` file one can setup a specific repository dev container to have the required authorization to pull and push it's project submodules repositories!